# How can I run a php script on a remote server?

Tags: php, apache, webserver, debian

I have a remote Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server where I want to do intervalled jobs like every 2 hours do this, at 12.00 do this. So, I wrote a php file which can do this but I have to start it via the browser and have to keep the browser window open to keep the script running. I heard I could execute a php script via console, but I don't have access to it.

How can I run the script without access to the console and without having my browser opened?

Comment: Do you have at least web based CPanel with cron management?

Comment: Use `curl` or `wget` from a shell script.

Comment: how do I use a shell script? and no, there is no cron

Comment: You don't know how to use a shell script, but you're sure there's no cron on Debian? You first need to get console, or shell, access. Or have someone who does create a cronjob for you as @MrTweek suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a cron job for this task. You can set this up on the server or on any other computer that runs at the given time.

On a Linux or Mac OS machine, open a terminal and type `crontab -e`.

Add something like this to the end of the file:

```
0 12 * * * wget http://url.com/your/script.php -O /dev/null
```

This will call the script every day at 12:00. Make sure `wget` is installed.